# Copy data from another sheet with 4 rows between each entry

Tags: vba, excel, offset

I am working with three excel sheets within the same workbook, Data, Calculations, and Results. As you will see, the entries in column A are the focus.

Using the formula `Data!A#` (row number), those entries from the A column of Data are copied onto column A of the Calculate page. Between each entry from Data, there are three rows of calculations. On the last page (Results), I am looking for a formula/VBA code that will allow me to grab column A from Calculate without the three rows in between them.

Currently, I am experimenting with an offset function: `OFFSET(Calculate!$A$2,(ROW()-1)*2,0)`. When I copy the forumla down, zeroes appear in some rows in place of the actual values. (Note A1 of Results is `=Calculate!A2`.)

How can I copy the entries from the Calculate sheet without a function returning zeroes as placeholders?

---

Data Sheet

[image: Data Sheet]

Calculations Sheet

[image: Calculations Sheet]

Results Sheet

[image: Results Sheet]

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using the `indirect` function:

```
=INDIRECT("Calculate!$A$"&(ROW()-1)*4+1)
```

With that formula in `A1:A4` of the results sheet, you should get the values you want from `A1`, `A5`, `A9`, `A13` on the Calculate sheet.